# C# Serial Port Write Byte

Tags: c#, serial-port, byte, send

Writing a single byte to the serial port in .NET 4.0  in C# causes a

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code

Every time a byte is sent to the SerialPort.

How do I write a single byte to the serial port?

```
    //Serial Init
    //Full fledged constuctor
    public NetCommManager(String portName, TransmissionType trans, String baud, String parity, String stopBits, String dataBits)
    {
        nc_baudRate = baud;
        nc_parity = parity;
        nc_stopBits = stopBits;
        nc_dataBits = dataBits;
        nc_portName = portName;
        nc_transType = trans;

        //now add an event handler
        comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(netComm_DataReceived);
    }
```

Config:

```
       _commManger = new NetCommManager(commPortNumber,                        
       NetCommManager.TransmissionType.Text, "19200", "None", "One", "8");
```

The Byte to be written:

```
_commManager.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte( 0x7B));
```

And `WriteByte` function is:

```
public void WriteByte(byte data)
        {
            //change data to array
            //byte[] dataArray = new byte[1];
            var dataArray = new byte[] {data};
            //dataArray[0] = data;
            comPort.Write(dataArray, 0, 1);   // <-- Exception is thrown here
        }
```

The NetCommManager class is very much based on [this example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/)

Comment: You are missing portion of the code that creates comPort object... and have several commented out lines for some reason.

Comment: The commented lines are other attempts to get it working in a different form

Comment: +1 for good effort. Note that you still missing `comPort = new...` portion :). Somehow Jeff E managed to figure it (+1 to the answer obviously). On commented out code - consider if it shows significantly different variant of code. I don't think it is case here - so I'd simply remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to `Open()` the `comPort`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx

Comment: This was correct. Some how the port was being closed before the Write was occurring. thanks!